# zpool replace erroring with does not contain an EFI label but it may contain partition

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

I had a drive fail in one of my vdevs setting the state of the zpool to degraded:
root@mediaserver:~# zpool status
  pool: zfsraid
 state: DEGRADED

So I started taking steps to replace the drive.

This is the id of the old disk: wwn-0x5000cca225f459d5
This is the id of the replacement disk: wwn-0x5000c5006e38bc61

**1)  offline old disk:**

```
 zpool offline zfsraid wwn-0x5000cca225f459d5
```

**2) Physically replace old disk with new disk**

**3) Issue replace command:**

```
 zpool replace -o ashift=12 zfsraid wwn-0x5000cca225f459d5 wwn-0x5000c5006e38bc61
```

The replace command fails with:

```
root@mediaserver:~# zpool replace -o ashift=12 zfsraid wwn-0x5000cca225f459d5 wwn-0x5000c5006e38bc61
**invalid vdev specification
use '-f' to override the following errors:
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c5006e38bc61 does not contain an EFI label but it may contain partition
information in the MBR.**
```

I can't seem to find any information to help.  A few forums said to use the -f option, but that seems sketchy.  There are no partitions listed on the new drive

```
root@mediaserver:~# fdisk -l /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c5006e38bc61

Disk /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c5006e38bc61: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c5006e38bc61 doesn't contain a valid partition table
root@mediaserver:~#
```

Do I have to run some command to wipe the new drive?

These are the last few lines in dmesg relating to the drive:

```
[420274.400024] scsi 11:0:8:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST3000DM001-1CH1 CC29 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[420274.400036] scsi 11:0:8:0: SATA: handle(0x000f), sas_addr(0x4433221107000000), phy(7), device_name(0x0000000000000000)
[420274.400039] scsi 11:0:8:0: SATA: enclosure_logical_id(0x5000000080000000), slot(4)
[420274.400130] scsi 11:0:8:0: atapi(n), ncq(y), asyn_notify(n), smart(y), fua(y), sw_preserve(y)
[420274.400134] scsi 11:0:8:0: qdepth(32), tagged(1), simple(0), ordered(0), scsi_level(7), cmd_que(1)
[420274.400502] sd 11:0:8:0: Attached scsi generic sg17 type 0
[420274.401375] sd 11:0:8:0: [sdr] 5860533168 512-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
[420274.401377] sd 11:0:8:0: [sdr] 4096-byte physical blocks
[420274.475163] sd 11:0:8:0: [sdr] Write Protect is off
[420274.475166] sd 11:0:8:0: [sdr] Mode Sense: 7f 00 10 08
[420274.475966] sd 11:0:8:0: [sdr] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[420274.554649]  sdr: unknown partition table
[420274.646245] sd 11:0:8:0: [sdr] Attached SCSI disk
```

This is the version of ubuntu i'm running:

```
Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS \n \l
```

root@mediaserver:~# uname -a

```
Linux mediaserver 3.5.0-44-generic #67~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 13 16:16:57 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 19):

@Matt, here's more detail.

*TL;DR:*

To make the new drive usable to replace the failed one, use **parted** and

```
mklabel GPT
```

*Extended Dance Remix Version:*

I had this exact issue and resolved it tonight. I'm using Debian Squeeze (6.0.10) with zfs on linux (0.6.0-1) and 3 x 1TB drives.

```
root@host:~# zpool status
  pool: dead_pool
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices are faulted in response to persistent errors.
    Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue functioning in a
    degraded state.
action: Replace the faulted device, or use 'zpool clear' to mark the device
    repaired.
 scan: resilvered 6.09G in 3h10m with 0 errors on Tue Sep  1 11:15:24 2015
config:

NAME                                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
dead_pool                               DEGRADED     0     0     0
  raidz1-0                              DEGRADED     0     0     0
    scsi-SATA_<orig_device_1>           ONLINE       0     0     0
    scsi-SATA_<orig_device_2>           ONLINE       0     0     0
    scsi-SATA_<orig_device_3>           FAULTED      0     3     0  too many errors
```

Yikes.  I went out this afternoon and bought a new drive of the same size (different make/model), powered off and installed it alongside the three existing zfs drives.  Power up again, and I watched the flood of I/O errors on the old drive as the system booted.  Terrifying stuff.

To replace the old with the new in zfs:

- Old disk ID: 1784233895253655477 (found using 'zdb')
- New disk device: /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_

  ```
  root@host:~# zpool offline dead_pool 1784233895253655477
  root@host:~# zpool replace dead_pool 1784233895253655477 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_<new_device_id>
  invalid vdev specification
  use '-f' to override the following errors:
  /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_<new_device_id> does not contain an EFI label but it may contain partition
  information in the MBR.
  ```

This is where @Matt's question comes in to play.  Use parted to setup a GPT (thanks [systutorials.com](http://www.systutorials.com/46294/making-gpt-partition-table-and-creating-partitions-with-parted-on-linux/)):

```
root@host:~# parted /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_<new_device_id>
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/sde
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) mklabel GPT                                                      
(parted) q                                                                
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.
```

Try the replace again:

```
root@host:~# zpool replace dead_pool 1784233895253655477 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_<new_device_id>
root@host:~#
```

Great it returned successfully.  Now check zpool again:

```
root@host:~# zpool status
  pool: dead_pool
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices is currently being resilvered.  The pool will
    continue to function, possibly in a degraded state.
action: Wait for the resilver to complete.
 scan: resilver in progress since Thu Sep  3 22:31:25 2015
    23.8G scanned out of 690G at 19.7M/s, 9h35m to go
    7.93G resilvered, 3.45% done
config:

    NAME                                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    dead_pool                               DEGRADED     0     0     0
      raidz1-0                              DEGRADED     0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_<orig_device_1>           ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_<orig_device_2>           ONLINE       0     0     0
        replacing-2                         OFFLINE      0     0     0
          scsi-SATA_<orig_device_3>         OFFLINE      0     0     0
          scsi-SATA_<new_device_id>         ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Woo! You rock. Sure glad I switched to ZFS mirrors from RAID5. Used to take days to replace a dead drive, and then one day it just completely shat the bed and I lost everything. Looks like it'll only take just over an hour to "resilver" this time.

Comment: Hey past self, this was amazing.  Thanks for posting it.  Just a quick note that when replacing a 1TB drive w/ a 2TB drive 6 years after our original post, I had to `zpool replace dead_pool 1784233895253655477 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_<new_device_id> -o ashift=9` after getting the `ashift` value from `zdb -C | grep ashift`.  Seems that the default value for 2TB drives is `12` which conflicts with the value of the existing pool and the error message of `zpool replace ...` without the `ashift` option is somewhat cryptic.

See @aXon's answer on this page for more `ashift` info.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it is important to find out, which ashift you have by issuing

```
 # zdb | grep ashift
```

If it is ashift=9, then you will have to replace your drive with -o ashift=9:

```
 zpool replace -o ashift=9 zfsraid wwn-0x5000cca225f459d5 wwn-0x5000c5006e38bc61
```

If you however have your pool set up as ashift=12, then the command you entered should be correct. Make sure, that you have zfs on linux v0.6.2 at least, which should be able to handle the shift option.

Comment: 12 seems to be the default, at least as of last year when I started working with ZFS at home.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a GPT Partition Table on the drive before replacing.

Comment: Please consider adding more detail to your answer; e.g. by specifying how a GPT Partition Table can be created.